# How can I wait for button click in android?

Tags: android, button, wait

I'm about to finish my Simon Says game, but I still have one crucial problem.

After my buttons are shown to the player, I have to wait (according to the level, e.g, if 5 buttons were showed to the user, I have to wait the user to click 5 buttons). I have searched around the internet, but the only answer was "You cannot freeze the android Application... blah blah blah".

Here it is my code:

```
public boolean playerTurn(){
    //Enable buttons
    buttonUp.setClickable(true);
    buttonDown.setClickable(true);
    buttonRight.setClickable(true);
    buttonLeft.setClickable(true);

    /*
     Wait for a button clicks depends on the level, but HOW?
     e.g, if the level is 5, I have to wait for 5 button clicks
     and after it, I can continue to run the code
     */


    /*Check if the user typed the correct order
     *If pressed the correct order
     *return true;
     *else
     *return false
    */
}
```

Comment: Find out more about a timer and set it in your code;

Comment: 5 times for each button or five times total?

Comment: five times total... If 5 buttons were showed, the user has to click 5 times

Comment: Fundamentally, you are going to have to switch from a "do this, then this, then this" paradigm, to an event-driven state-machine type of approach, where each user input even method moves you closer to achieving some goal.  A count of buttons pushed is a simple case, a more complicated one could be requiring that the user push certain buttons in a certain order - each correct one advances the state towards a goal, while an incorrect one resets the state to the beginning.

Comment: You program will spend most of it's time sitting in system code waiting for a button push, and only very brief slices of time running your code in the event methods that the system calls when the user pushes a button.

Comment: understood, but you have some suggestion? Can you show me the simplest case?

Answer (score 4):

For each button do something like this:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click   
                buttonsPressedCount++;

                if (buttonsPressedCount >= 5) {
                  // Do whatever you wanted to do
                }
            }
        });
```

In this way, each button will listen for clicks and update a global counter.  Finally when your global counter is greater than 5, you can proceed.  The application is never "paused", it just only moves on the next section when five buttons have been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not near a computer so no code example (will post later). Basically, you can set a class level counter. Provide an OnClickListener for each button - can be same or different. In the listener increment the counter and check if it reached 5 or not. If it did, check the pattern and clear counter.

Comment: hmm... it sounds nice KMLong, can you post later? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Will do. Will be about 4 hours or so.

Comment: See my answer above for this approach.

Comment: Thanks hatboysam! Just sat down to write the code example and saw your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RxBindings](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) for this purpose. Convert the clicks into a stream of events, and add a subscriber to it, which will react to the event of a click.

Here's how you can do it,

```
RxView.clicks(button)
.take(5)
.subscribe(aVoid ->
{
    // Do your stuff
});
```

This will add a subscriber to the click event, and will only take the first five events.

Hope it helps.